# Explain this timer - How Can I set to every 5 minutes? C#

Tags: c#, timer

I have this line of code

```
new Timer(_CallBackProcessABC, null, 5000, Timeout.Infinite);
```

Can someone explain what this line does? After how much time this is executing?

How can I set it to execute after every 5 minutes?

Comment: have you considered reading the online docs?

Comment: [What's wrong with the MSDN help for it?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x96zfy7.aspx) (Hint: There are 5 * 60 * 1000 milliseconds in 5 minutes) Note that the LAST parameter is the repeat time.

Comment: That's what is documentation for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx

Comment: It's due time is 5 seconds but it runs infinite. So not a real timer because it runs once.

Comment: @TimSchmelter the Timeout.infinite what does that do.

Comment: By the way I read the MSDN documentation but could not relate it to my Question. @MatthewWatson

Comment: @DawoodAwan It, er, well, it sets in infinite timeout... Anyway the documentation for the last parameter states `The time interval between invocations of callback, in milliseconds` - is that the bit you can't understand?

Comment: @DawoodAwan: It says that the timer has no automatic repetition. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x96zfy7.aspx): _"Specify Timeout.Infinite to disable periodic signaling."_

Comment: So what this line does is that it calls the process _CallBackProcessABC every 5 seconds? and doesnot repeat? @TimSchmelter

Comment: @DawoodAwan No, the code in your example above makes the timer call `_CallBackProcessABC` once after 5 seconds, and never again. There is no repeating.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I don't know why the question was downvoted. As I read the documentation and needed help as I was confused. Anyway thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close because you don't seem to even "demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved". If the docs don't make sense for this simple API, perhaps it's time to do something else, or to open a question about how better to read and understand the docs on one of other stackexchange sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new Timer(_CallBackProcessABC, null, 5000, Timeout.Infinite);
```

it's called after 5000 miliseconds

for running it EVERY 5 minutes: 5*1000*60 ms

```
new Timer(_CallBackProcessABC, null, 0, 300000);
```

as said [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x96zfy7.aspx) `period` is in miliseconds

```
public Timer(
    TimerCallback callback,
    Object state,
    int dueTime,
    int period
)
```

> Type: System.Int64 The time interval between invocations of callback,
>   in milliseconds. Specify Timeout.Infinite to disable periodic
>   signaling.

EDIT:

to run it every 5 minutes you need to specify `period` (last parameter) not `dueTime`.

Answer (score 2):

The `5000` represents milliseconds, you need to use `300000`, which is `1000 m/s * 60 * 5`

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
new Timer(_CallBackProcessABC, null, 1000 * 60 * 5, Timeout.Infinite);
```

The timer works in milliseconds, if you use it like this, the compiler will optimize the calculation at compiletime, but it is more readable like this.

Answer (score 1):

As explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah1h85ch.aspx

The 5000 is the time in milliseconds, so you can change it to:

```
new Timer(_CallBackProcessABC, null, 300000, Timeout.Infinite);
```

In which 300000 represents 5 minutes in milliseconds.